# pyqtgraph: add legend item for scatter plots

Tags: pyqtgraph

I'm using pyqtgraph and I'd like to add an item in the legend for scatter plots.

I've adapted the example code to demonstrate:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Demonstrates basic use of LegendItem

"""
import initExample ## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

plt = pg.plot()
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Legend')
plt.addLegend()

c1 = plt.plot([1,3,2,4], pen='r', name='red plot')
c2 = plt.plot([2,1,4,3], pen='g', fillLevel=0, fillBrush=(255,255,255,30), name='green plot')
c3 = plt.plot([4,3,2,1], pen=None, symbol='o', symbolPen='y', symbolBrush='r', name="point plot")


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

What I get as a result is:
[image: plot image]

How do I add an appropriate legend item?

Answer (score 2):

The current release of pyqtgraph does not support this feature. 
However, it is supported in the unstable branch. You can copy LegendItem.py from the unstable branch here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~luke-campagnola/pyqtgraph/inp/view/head:/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/LegendItem.py